# How to show information in div with Jquery & Google maps v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm wondering how to show information of a marker (after Onclick) outside the map in a div instead of showing it in the standard Google maps infowindow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to register and event listener for that marker... so when the user clicks it a function is fired.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: parliament
     });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', showInfo);

function showInfo() {
  //display info whereever you like.
}
```

P.S. This is just sample code so you need to adapt for your needs.

Hope this helps